# Change innerHTML of element with JS eventlistener

Tags: javascript

I am trying to add a event listener to a anchor tag with id of "rta". After getting the element by id I am trying to change the innerHTML of a element with class of "inner-content" but the change does work. What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

HTML Element

```
<div><a href="#" id="rta"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/whoLELi.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
```

JS

```
var rta = document.getElementById("rta");

rta.addEventListener("click", function() {
  querySelector(".inner-content").innerHTML = "RTA Content";
});
```

The full code is at this codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNvZLgP

```js
// change inner content with even handler
var rta = document.getElementById("rta");

rta.addEventListener("click", function() {
  querySelector(".inner-content").innerHTML = "RTA Content";
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 10 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #606060;
}

p {
  color: #96ceb4;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner-menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;  
}

img {
 height: 30px;
}

.header-img {
  height: 60px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}


.flexbox-header > div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header :nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.grid-page > div {
    color: #ffeead;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.flexbox-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffeead;
}

.flexbox-header :nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.grid-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 600px 80px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #D5D8DC; 
}

.menu {
  grid-column: span 1;
  background-color: #3C5197;
}

.content {
  grid-column: span 11;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header > div {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.inner-grid-page > div {
    color: #606060;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.inner-grid-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 35px 100% 20px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.inner-header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffeead;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.inner-header > div {
  padding: 60px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.inner-content {
  grid-column: span 10;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.inner-footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #88d8b0;
}

#rta-img {
  height: 65px;
}

a#rta {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a#csi {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a#fusion {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
}

a#docs {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-header">
  <div>HOME</div>
  <div>SEARCH</div>
  <div>LOGOUT</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid-page">
  <div class="header">
    <div><a href="#" id="rta"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/whoLELi.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="csi"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XyOCkuy.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="fusion"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E08OPQ4.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="docs"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tt5zNZ0.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-grid-page">
      <div class="inner-header">
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM1</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM2</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM3</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>TIEM4</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>TIEM5</div></a>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6TBaHEI.jpg" class="logo"></li><br>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rgLRv9g.jpg" class="logo"></li><br>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FPpRLQP.jpg?1" class="logo"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-content">
        CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="inner-footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `querySelector` is not a standalone function

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: @mplungjan sorry for the inconvenience that was silly already deleted my answer

Comment: Thanks CertainPerformance? I forgot to start with document.querySelector instead of just querySelector.

Answer (score 2):

1. it is `document.querySelector`
2. I answer because I can see this turning into a non-DRY solution - note the CSS for `.header a` too

```js
var content = {
  "rta"   : "This is <b>RTA</b> Content",
  "csi"    : "This is <b>CSI</b> Content",
  "fusion" : "This is <b>fusion</b> Content",
  "docs"   : "This is <b>docs</b> Content"
}
// change inner content with even handler


document.querySelector(".header").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target = e.target;
  console.log(target.tagName)
  if (target.tagName==="IMG") {
    document.querySelector(".inner-content").innerHTML = content[target.parentNode.id]
  }  
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 10 auto;
  font-size: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #606060;
}

p {
  color: #96ceb4;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 2%;
}

li {
  padding: 5px;
}

.inner-menu > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logo {
  height: 100px;  
}

img {
 height: 30px;
}

.header-img {
  height: 60px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 0;
}


.flexbox-header > div {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.header :nth-child(2) {
    padding: 0 40px;
}

.grid-page > div {
    color: #ffeead;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.flexbox-header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffeead;
}

.flexbox-header :nth-child(3) {
    margin-left: auto;
}

.grid-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 80px 600px 80px;
}

.header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #D5D8DC; 
}

.menu {
  grid-column: span 1;
  background-color: #3C5197;
}

.content {
  grid-column: span 11;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #000000;
}

.header > div {
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.inner-grid-page > div {
    color: #606060;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

.inner-grid-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 35px 100% 20px;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.inner-header {
  grid-column: span 12;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ffeead;
  padding: 0 40px;
}

.inner-header > div {
  padding: 60px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

.inner-menu {
  grid-column: span 2;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.inner-content {
  grid-column: span 10;
  background-color: #ffcc5c;
}

.inner-footer {
  grid-column: span 12;
  background-color: #88d8b0;
}

#rta-img {
  height: 65px;
}

.header a {
 display: block;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox-header">
  <div>HOME</div>
  <div>SEARCH</div>
  <div>LOGOUT</div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="grid-page">
  <div class="header">
    <div><a href="#" id="rta"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/whoLELi.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="csi"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/XyOCkuy.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="fusion"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/E08OPQ4.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
    <div><a href="#" id="docs"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/tt5zNZ0.png" class="header-img"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
      <li>Link</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="inner-grid-page">
      <div class="inner-header">
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM1</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM2</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>ITEM3</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>TIEM4</div></a>
        <a href="#"><div>TIEM5</div></a>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-menu">
        <ul>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/6TBaHEI.jpg" class="logo"></li><br>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/rgLRv9g.jpg" class="logo"></li><br>
          <li><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FPpRLQP.jpg?1" class="logo"></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="inner-content">
        CONTENT
      </div>
      <div class="inner-footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
</div>
```